# Assign ranks to records and keep the same rank based on condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose we have table below

| user_id | event_name | event_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | subscribe | 1 |
| Adam | renewal | 4 |
| Adam | renewal | 5 |
| Adam | irrelevant event name | 6 |
| Adam | churn | 7 |
| Adam | subscribe | 10 |
| Adam | renewal | 20 |

Notes: event_time is actually in milliseconds but i just simplified things.

I wanted to add numbers for each row so that final table looks like this:

| user | event_name | event_time | subscription_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | subscribe | 1 | 1 |
| Adam | renewal | 4 | 1 |
| Adam | renewal | 5 | 1 |
| Adam | irrelevant event name | 6 | null |
| Adam | churn | 7 | 1 |
| Adam | subscribe | 10 | 2 |
| Adam | renewal | 20 | 2 |
| Adam | renewal | 30 | 2 |
| Adam | churn | 40 | 2 |

What final table means is that first row is Adam's first subscription so subscription id is 1. Second row means Adam renewed his subscription of id 1 so renewal event is for subscription id 1. After n renewal events his first subscription ended(churned). So churn event row should have subscription id 1. After some time Adam resubscribes so this subscription should have id of 2 and every renewal events and churn event after this subscription should have id of 2 as well.

Basically whenever event_name is subscribe increment subscription_id by 1 and assign it for all relevant events, if event_name is irrelevant just assign null to subscription_id

Hope i explained my question well.
Thanks for your effort and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below query.

```sql
SELECT *,
       -- if event_name is irrelevant just assign null to subscription_id 
       IF(event_name IN ('subscribe', 'renewal', 'churn'),
          -- Everytime a user subscribes again, the user gets a new id increased by one.
          COUNTIF(event_name = 'subscribe') OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY event_time),
          NULL
       ) AS subscription_id
  FROM sample_table;
```

[image]

Comment: can you please add an explanation