# Add derived column from existing column based on a condition in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose we have table below

| user_id | event_name | event_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | subscribe | 1 |
| Adam | renewal | 4 |
| Adam | renewal | 5 |
| Adam | churn | 7 |
| Adam | subscribe | 10 |
| Adam | renewal | 20 |

Notes:

- event_time is actually in milliseconds but i just simplified things.
- I asked a similar question and got a pretty good answer in here: [Assign ranks to records and keep the same rank based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74488866/assign-ranks-to-records-and-keep-the-same-rank-based-on-condition), may be useful for those looking for an answer to this question.

I wanted to add numbers for each row so that final table looks like this:

| user | event_name | event_time | subscription_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | subscribe | 1 | 1 |
| Adam | renewal | 4 | 1 |
| Adam | renewal | 5 | 1 |
| Adam | churn | 7 | 1 |
| Adam | subscribe | 10 | 10 |
| Adam | renewal | 20 | 10 |
| Adam | renewal | 30 | 10 |
| Adam | churn | 40 | 10 |

To explain, each renewal event belongs to preceding subscribe event. I need a derived column that shows the time for that subscription event. Therefore derived column should be same as a subscription time of that event. My final purpose is to find out number of renewals/churns etc for a given subscription time

Hope i explained my question well.
Thanks for your effort and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach similar to previous my answer.

```sql
SELECT *,
       IF(event_name IN ('subscribe', 'renewal', 'churn'),
          -- below will return most recent time of *subscribe* event
          LAST_VALUE(IF(event_name = 'subscribe', event_time, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY event_time),
          NULL
       ) AS subscription_time
  FROM sample_table;
```

**Query results**

[image]